# Mongo find em array dentro de collection

Tags: shell, mongodb, meteor

Bom pessoal, essa é minha saída com o find normal:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57be6168ce98ad853a96282f"), 
    "nome" : "Mercado Padrão", 
    "userId" : "o4wQ2i4Dt7cAMNf9A", 
    "produtos" : [ 
         { 
             "nome" : "coca cola", 
             "vds" : [ 
                 { "desc" : "Sódio", "qtd" : "0,5", "vd" : "mg" } 
              ], 
              "est" : "100", "preco" : "5.50", "sku" : "KU177" 
         } 
     ] 
}
```

Minha dúvida é como fazer um consulta que retorno só a lista de produtos de um userId especifico.

exemplo:
 Quero consultar todos produtos do userId: o4wQ2i4Dt7cAMNf9A.

Comment: Sem o "schema" do banco fica um pouquinho complicado, mas nao é o caso de um simples find? `db.tabela.find({userId:'o4wQ2i4Dt7cAMNf9A'})`. Comecei no mongo a pouco tempo mas ate onde sei isso vai te retornar todos os registros com o `userId == o4wQ2i4Dt7cAMNf9A`

Answer (score 0):

Isso irá retornar uma lista com os arrays inteiros para o usuário. Se o usuário possuir mais de um documento na coleção, múltiplos arrays retornarão:

```
db.suacolecao.find({userId: "xxxxxxxxx"}, {produtos: 1})
```

Se você precisar combinar todos esses possíveis arrays em um único array, você precisará utilizar o *[Aggregation Framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)*. Há um exemplo muito parecido com este problema [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19440087/21420).

Answer (score 0):

Usa o aggregate e o $match Amigo. Para organizar seu filtro, use $project:

```
db.XXXXX.aggregate([{
 $match: { userId: "o4wQ2i4Dt7cAMNf9A"} },{
 $project:{ userId: 1, produtos.nome: 1} }])
```